# Idiom for something that can not be defined, such as job satisfaction

Tags: idioms

What could be the idioms used for saying something that can not be defined,  such as job satisfaction.

Comment: First, if it can't be defined, it's tricky to determine what you're talking about. Second, job satisfaction can be defined.

Comment: What's wrong with _indefinable_?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean something that can not be *quantified*, I would suggest "intangible", as in "One of the intangibles of my position is job satisfaction".

As I'm new here, I can't post this as a comment.

Comment: Or "The intangibles".